# What Wav Format should I use for recording audio and Recognizing Speech in it?

Tags: naudio

I am creating a windows service which will connect to audio input device and record audio using NAudio WaveIn. And this is flow :

1. 1st level of Speech detection using VOSK Speech Recognition and Add recorded audio to Memory Stream.
2. if Speech is Recognized,  save memory stream to wav file.
3. 2nd level of Speech Recognition using Microsoft Cognitive Speech Service to read from wav file.

My question, what wave format should I use while saving as wav file, to improvise the speech recognition accuracy of Cognitive speech service.?

_waveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1);

or

_waveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(16000, 16, 1);

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The higher sample rate will take twice as much disk space but will be slightly higher quality, so might give slightly better results. I recommend you try submitting the same audio at both sample rates though and see whether there is any difference.